# Issue with Cython Compilation and File Movement in setup.py

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, cython

I'm currently working on a project that involves compiling Cython `.pyx` files into shared object (`.c`) files using `setup.py`. Additionally, I've created a test suite named `test_setup.py` using `pytest` to ensure the functionality is correct. However, I've encountered a puzzling issue with the file movement after compilation.

**Description:**

1. **setup.py:**

   In the `setup.py` script, I'm using the `setuptools` library and `Cython.Build` to compile a `.pyx` file into a shared object file. The script also includes a logic to rename and move the original `.pyx` file to an "archives" directory. The primary goal is to build the extension and maintain an organized archive of the original `.pyx` files.

   ```py
    import os
    from setuptools import setup
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
    import numpy as np

    def build_extension():
        # Define the name of the original .pyx file
        original_filename = "cython_numpy_test.pyx"

        # Get the current directory where setup.py is located
        current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

        # Path to the original .pyx file in the current directory
        original_filepath = os.path.join(current_directory, original_filename)

        # Extract the base name and extension of the original file
        base_name, ext = os.path.splitext(original_filename)

        # Create a new file name and directory
        new_filename = f"PYX_{base_name}{ext}"
        new_directory = "PYX_archives"

        # Create the new directory if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(new_directory):
            os.makedirs(new_directory)

        # Configuration for building Cython extension
        setup(
            name=base_name,  # Extracted base name without extension
            ext_modules=cythonize(original_filepath),  # Compile the original .pyx file
            include_dirs=[np.get_include()]  # Include NumPy headers
        )

        # Rename and move the original .pyx file to the new directory
        os.rename(
            original_filepath,
            os.path.join(new_directory, new_filename)
        )

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        build_extension()
   ```
2. **test_setup.py:**

   In my `test_setup.py`, I have set up a testing scenario using `pytest`. The script creates a temporary directory and simulates the build process by creating a sample `.pyx` file, running the `build_extension()` function, and verifying the expected outcomes. The test case includes assertions to ensure that the C compilation is successful and that the compiled C file is moved to the right location.

```py
      import os
      import pytest
      import subprocess
      import setup

      def test_setup(tmpdir):
         temp_test_dir = tmpdir.mkdir("test_setup")

         # Define the name and directory of the original .pyx file
         original_filename = "numpy_permutations_combinations.pyx"
         original_path = temp_test_dir / original_filename

         # Create a sample .pyx file in the temporary directory
         with open(original_path, "w") as f:
            f.write("# Sample.pyx file content")

         # Run the setup.build_extension() function
         setup.build_extension()

         # Verify that the new .pyx file is created in the new directory
         new_directory = temp_test_dir / "PYX_archives"
         new_file_path = new_directory / f"PYX_{os.path.splitext(original_filename)[0]}.pyx"
         assert new_file_path.exists()

         # Verify that the original .pyx file is moved to the new directory
         assert not original_path.exists()
         assert (new_directory / original_filename).exists()

         # Compile the generated C file using subprocess
         c_filename = f"PYX_{os.path.splitext(original_filename)[0]}.c"
         c_file_path = new_directory / c_filename
         assert c_file_path.exists()

         # Use subprocess to compile the C file
         compiled_c_filename = f"PYX_{os.path.splitext(original_filename)[0]}.so"
         subprocess.run(["gcc", "-shared", "-o", compiled_c_filename, c_filename], cwd=new_directory)
         assert (new_directory / compiled_c_filename).exists()

      if __name__ == "__main__":
         pytest.main()
```

**Tests in test_setup.py:**

- Create a temporary directory for testing using `tmpdir` fixture.
- Generate a sample `.pyx` file within the temporary directory.
- Simulate the build process by calling the `build_extension()` function from the `setup` module.
- Verify that the new `.pyx` file is created in the expected location.
- Confirm that the original `.pyx` file is moved to the designated "archives" directory.
- Compile the generated C file using `subprocess.run()` and assert the compiled `.so` file's existence.

**Issue:**

Despite the fact that the C compilation process appears to be working perfectly in my tests, I've noticed that the original `.pyx` file isn't moved to the "archives" directory with the modified `PYX_{filename}.pyx` name, as intended. This is unexpected behavior, and I'm trying to identify the root cause of this issue.

**Request:**

I'm seeking guidance and suggestions on why the file movement logic in `setup.py` might not be functioning as expected, even though the C compilation seems to be successful in my tests.